# Sometime slow query count in postgres

Tags: postgresql

It usually takes a lot of time for the first time of a period. after that, it will take a similar time.

Table size: 6.4M

```sql
explain analyze
SELECT count(*) as "count", "bookId" 
FROM "libraries"
WHERE "bookId" IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
GROUP BY "bookId";
```

### Execution time

- round 1: 4500ms
- round 2: 105ms
- round 3: 92ms
- round 4: 93ms

### Explain Analyze

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..17520.53 rows=4308 width=33) (actual time=438.948..2258.747 rows=9 loops=1)
  Group Key: "bookId"
  ->  Index Only Scan using "libraries_bookId" on libraries  (cost=0.56..17445.19 rows=6452 width=25) (actual time=0.798..2249.024 rows=32306 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("bookId" = ANY ('{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}'::text[]))
        Heap Fetches: 32306
Planning time: 0.254 ms
Execution time: 2258.813 ms
```

Comment: Can you try to add `EXPLAIN PLAN` at the beginning of the request then post the result ?

Comment: That sounds like a caching effect. The first query has to read from disk, the later queries already find data cached in memory.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Ok, I added it to above.

Comment: You can see the time it spends on-disk when you execute `SET track_io_timing TO on` and then re-execute an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`